# C# Displaying Json variables in labels in another form from class

Tags: c#, json

I have this class:

```
public class Userinfo
{

    public Userinfo()
    {

    }
    public static async Task<List<Information>> Login(string Username, string Password)
    {
        string str = "https://somesite.com/log.php";
        string[] cID = new string[] { "act=qwjFpPXuGexZBHDJEreZrAUH&CID=", "&username=", Username, "&password=", Password };
        string str1 = string.Concat(cID);

        using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            webClient.Proxy = null;
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string str2 = webClient.UploadString(str, str1)
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Information>>(str2);
            return result;
        }
     }
  }
```

Which returns this JSON

```
[{"username":"fakeuser","email":"fakeemail@outlook.com","plan":"1","activationdate":"18\/12\/20","terminationdate":"18\/01\/21"}]
```

What I want to do is set in another form the data inside the `result` variable in labels so they can display the actual content. The problem is that if I debug the code the variable seems to be empty. If I make a break and hover the mouse over the variable it doesn't show anything and it doesn't even appear on the variable list. So, what am I doing wrong?

This is the code I have in the form where I have the labels:

```
private async void Filldata()
    {
        var result = await Userinfo.Login("username", "password");
        
        label11.Text = result.Select(x => x.username).FirstOrDefault();
        label18.Text = result.Select(x => x.email).FirstOrDefault();
        label19.Text = result.Select(x => x.plan).FirstOrDefault();
        label20.Text = result.Select(x => x.activationdate).FirstOrDefault();
        label21.Text = result.Select(x => x.terminationdate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

And here is my class where I deserialize the JSON:

```
public class Information
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string plan { get; set; }
    public string activationdate { get; set; }
    public string terminationdate { get; set; }

}
```

I think it's worth mentioning that the classes are separate. Userinfo and Information are their own classes.

What am I missing and how can I solve this?

Posted again because I haven't been able to solve this.

Comment: For debugging, make sure you are using the debug config and not release config in Visual Studio.

Comment: Why would a function that is declared to return `async Task<List<Information>>` and which ends with a call to `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` _return this JSON_ (the JSON you show). Can you update your question to make it make sense?

Comment: Can you dump the result to the immediate window?  Can you log it somewhere?  There is no way for anyone to reproduce your specific issue as written.

Comment: I dont think you have to reproduce anything. My issue is that I have that Json and I want to show the content of the variable `result` which contains the deserialized Json in a label that is in another usercontrol. Why is that so diffcult to understand? Is my procedure correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Well, you need to describe in a way we can understand it. Your `Login` method is declared `async` and returns a Task, but it contains no `await` statements - so it isn't really async; I have no idea what happens then. You are using `WebClient`, have you considered `HttpClient`? When you debug this, does `str2` contain the JSON you say the function returns? When you deserialize that, are you getting the objects you expect. The way to fix this is to debug it; as it stands, we aren't able to do it from afar